# Filter and Loop Through A List Of Records For Min Date

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Looking for help with some VBA.

I have a worksheet with a list of records that has a: Status cell, Date cell and Job cell.

When I change the Status cell to "Filled" in the active record I want to filter the list of records to only look at records in the list that have the same entry as in the Job cell of the active record,  say the letter "a". If there are older dates than in the active record Date cell of the filtered list, I would want to enter the older date (Date-1) in the active Date cell.

Example

```
  Status        Date            Job
1 Sent          3/10/2018       a
2 Sent          5/10/2018       b
3 Filled        4/10/2018       a
4 Rejected      5/15/2018       c
5 Interviewed   6/14/2018       b
6 Sent          5/15/2018       a
```

Record 3 would get Date changed to 3/9/2018 form 4/10/2018 when the Status cell is changed to "Filled"

Comment: Why 3/9/2018, shouldn't it be 3/10/2018?

Comment: No, because I want the updated date to be the oldest date, so when I do a sort it sorts to the top.

Comment: Not sure what happened to your code, it worked great, was able to deal with the Date - 1 day another way.
Couldn't figure out the relationships, wanted to do the exact same thing but instead of updating the active records Date I want to update column L, Value, 
with the maximum amount in the same range defined by col K again. Everything exactly the same except the column to update, which would be L instead of H. Could you tell me what the numbers changes would be in the code?

Col D = Status    Col H = Date     Col K =  Job  Col L= Value